# How can I write code for Hello Test in HTML

Tags: html

How to write code for "Hello HTML" in HTML

`<h1>Hello HTML</h1>`

Answer (score 0):

You can save your `<h1>Hello HTML</h1>` code as a file with ".html" *(Example:-index.html)* extension, which will shows your "Hello HTML" text as you expect in the browser when you double click the saved ".html" *(Example:-index.html)* file. - This is the answer for your question.

But there are some rules and code formats are exists to start the html learning. Follow some tutorials like w3schools, codecademy first and learn the basics then you will got an clear idea in that.